SSRS Wildcard Search for several words in a single field
I have a query with a wildcard parameter to search for any part of an action in the 'regardingobjectidname' field:
WHERE FilteredActivityPointer.regardingobjectidname LIKE '%' + @Action + '%'
The problem is that I need to search for more than 1 word, ie I need to know if the words 'delayed' AND 'discharge' appear in the 'regardingobjectidname' field. I was hoping to be able to add 2 words in the report parameter preview, separated by a semi-colon or something, but can't get this to work. I know to allow multiple values in the parameter properties, but because this is a wildcard search, there is no dropdown list of available values. Any help is greatly appreciated

There are almost certainly better/faster ways of doing this, but this works OK.
You need to do this work in your dataset query. You can pass in a text string such as "delay; discharge" to this code and it will return the 'sentences' (in this example) that match all the words passed in, matching as wildcards.
-- create a table for the stuff we want to search, this is in place of your existing table
CREATE TABLE Sentences ( SentenceID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY, SentenceText NVARCHAR(255) );
    INSERT INTO Sentences (SentenceText) VALUES 
    ('The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.'), 
    ('The quick brown fox is quick.'), 
    ('A lazy dog lays on the warm sand.'), 
    ('The fox and the dog are friends.'), 
    ('Quick movements are essential for the fox.'), 
    ('The sand was warm and inviting.'), 
    ('A quick brown fox is agile.'), 
    ('Lazy days are best enjoyed with friends.'), 
    ('The dog enjoys warm sunny days.'), 
    ('Brown foxes are quick and clever.');
    
    -- The real code starts here
    -- This is the string you will pass in from SSRS via a simple text parameter
    DECLARE @searchTerms varchar(100)= 'fox; dog';
    -- split the string and put each word in a table
    CREATE TABLE SearchTerms(word varchar(50));
    INSERT INTO SearchTerms(word)
        SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(Value)) FROM  string_split(@searchTerms, ';');
    
    -- join the two tables, there should be a join for each word so we group the results and count how many in each group we have. If the count is the same as the number of words we're trying to match then return the row.
    SELECT 
        SentenceID, SentenceText
        FROM Sentences s 
            JOIN SearchTerms w on s.SentenceText like '%' + w.word + '%'
        GROUP BY SentenceID, SentenceText
        HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM SearchTerms)

Here's a fiddle showing it in action.
You don't need the SentenceID or primary key, for this to work, you can remove these and it will work fine, I left them in because I'm lazy and generated the sample sentences offline.

Update after OP response

You can also do this without creating any tables, ignoring the table that populates the sample data, here's the code you need.
-- YOUR CODE STARTS HERE
DECLARE @searchTerms varchar(100)= 'fox; dog'; -- do not declare this in your dataset query (comment it out), pass it in from SSRS as a parameter.

SELECT 
    SentenceID, SentenceText
    FROM Sentences s 
        JOIN (SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(Value)) as word FROM  string_split(@searchTerms, ';')) w on s.SentenceText like '%' + w.word + '%'
    GROUP BY SentenceID, SentenceText
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 
          (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM  string_split(@searchTerms, ';'))


Thanks for this - I was hoping it would be easier than this lol. The permissions we have in our organisation dont allow creation of tables unfortunately

You don't need to create a table. The example shows creating a temp table (which I bet you do have access to), but you could just use this inline, I'll update the answer to show how.

Answer updated and fiddle also updated to show solution with no tables created, other than the sample data table which you obviously won't need.
